# Question about Galois theory.

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field and let $I$ be a non-empty set, call $\Phi:=\{f_i(x)\}_{i \in I}$ a family of separable polynomials of $K[x]$. Take $L$ be an extension of $K$ such that $L$ is the least field which contains the roots of $f_i(x), \forall i \in I$.

a)Show that $L$ is separable.

b)Let $\alpha \in L, $ show that there exists a field $F$ such that $K \subset F \subset L$, $\alpha \in F$ and $F:K$ is Galois and finite. Conclude that $L:K$ is Galois.

$\textbf{My attempt}:$

a) There is a Theorem and it must solve that: $L:K$ is separable $\iff$ L is obtained for ajoint of separable elements of $K$.

b) My Idea is to take $F = K(\alpha,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha, \alpha_2,\dots, \alpha_n$ are roots of $m_\alpha$ (minimal polynomial of $\alpha$). $F$ is separable and since $F$ is splitting field of $m_\alpha$, we have $F:K$ Galois. But I don't know how to prove that $F \subset L$, because $L$ is not necessarily normal, its possible that there exist some $\alpha_i \notin L$.

Futhermore, how can I conclude that $L:K$ is galois?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F/k$ be an algebraic field extension. Next properties are equivalent:

(1) Every $k$-embedding $\sigma: F \to \bar{k}$ (algebraic closure) - is a $k$-automorphism of $F$;

(2) $F$ is splitting field for some family of polynomials in $k[x]$;

(3) For every irreducible polynomial $f \in k[x]$ with a root in $F$ and for the splitting field of $f$ - $k( \alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n)$ - we have:  $k( \alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n) \subseteq F$.

Each of these properties can be viewed as definition of normal extension. It's a standart fact. For example, you can find proof in Lang's Algebra.

So, your have already shown that your extension is separable. Now you can see that splitting field of $m_\alpha$ - $F$ - is galois and lie in $L$ - that is the third property from above list gives solution for your (b)-problem.

All in all, your field $L$ is generated over $k$ by all roots of polynomials which belong to the family of separated  polynomials $\Phi:=\{f_i(x)\}_{i \in I}$, therefore $L$ is separable and normal over $k$ i.e. galois.

Comment: Where I can find the proof of $(2) \Rightarrow (3)??$ I didn't find in Lang's Algebra.

Comment: @Joãonani For example, you can look here: "Algebra", Serge Lang,  Revised third edition (Springer), chapter v "Algebraic extensions", §3 "Splitting fields and normal extensions", Theorem 3.3.

Comment: This theorem can be found in every edition, including the oldest one, in chapter "Algebraic extensions", § "Splitting fields and normal extensions" - only numeration for chapter can be different.

Comment: Ok, I've found that, thank you.